# Subscribing to events

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

When subscribing to events in .NET do I need to create a new instance of the delegate such as

```
toolbarControl1.OnUploadEventHandler += 
    new ToolbarControl.UploadEventHandler(toolbarControl1_OnUpload);
```

Or is it better to do the following?

```
toolbarControl1.OnUploadEventHandler += toolbarControl1_OnUpload;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this link may help answer your question. I can't view the page at the moment, but the result on Google looked promising. :) *http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson14.aspx*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second one takes less coding and both mean the same.

You might want to consider using generic version of EventHandler - `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`. You will save on declaring all those delegates.

You can also use lambda expressions, ie.

```
toolbarControl1.OnUploadEventHandler += 
    (sender, args) => { /* Your code goes here */ };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do both, so its your preference.

You can also do things like this for very simple handlers to save writing a delegate function:

```
toolbarControl1.OnUploadEventHandler += (s, e) => uploadCount +=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code speaks for itself:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var prog = new Program();

        // Demonstrate that they are equivalent
        prog.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(prog.SomeMethod);
        prog.SomeEvent -= prog.SomeMethod; // Sugar for new EventHandler(prog.SomeMethod)
        Console.WriteLine("Number of SomeEvent subscribers is {0}", (prog.SomeEvent != null ? prog.SomeEvent.GetInvocationList() : new Delegate[0]).Length);

        // Why are they equivalent?
        var d1 = new EventHandler(prog.SomeMethod);
        var d2 = new EventHandler(prog.SomeMethod);
        Console.WriteLine("Delegates are reference equal {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(d1, d2));
        Console.WriteLine("Delegates are equivalent {0}", d1 == d2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent.  The second one only provides better readability.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent unless you need to keep a reference to the delegate so as to unsubscribe.

Comment: No, even if you unsubscribe you can use the same syntax - you'd end up creating two equal delegates, as they'd both have the same target and the same method.

Comment: @Maslow: I'm saying that if you unsubscribe with a reference to a new but *equal* delegate, it will work just fine. So you can use `toolbarControl1.OnUploadEventHandler -= toolbarControl1_OnUpload;` to unsubscribe with no problems.

Comment: I seem to remember this not working, but I don't remember the exact circumstances.  It may not have been a named method that I was pointing to.